# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')

Tags: sinch

In Safari 10.1.2 I'm getting the below error when sourcing `<script src="//cdn.sinch.com/latest/sinch.min.js"></script>`

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia') sinch.min.js:1:148652`

This stops the client from being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Sinch does not support safari, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll switch to REST and handle the calls myself on the backend. Consider this a +1 to please offer client side Safari support for SMS verification as it would have simplified my life a bit.